# Merge Array Into Single Outside Loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am attempting to do the following.  I have the following array "item_code" within an array:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Wes
    [email] => no@no.com
    [duration] => 2 days
    [comment] => stuff
    [item_code] => Array
        (
            [0] => USE4220HP9,USE4220HP8,USE4220HP7,USE4220HP6,USE4220HP5
            [1] => USE0463V8E,USE1066KYN,USE0463V7S,USE1066KYS,USE1066KYK

        )

)
```

The item_code array can potentially have multiple keys - more than two.  What I want to do is turn the item_code array into a single array where each USExxxxx value is a single key within the array.

I understand how to use something like foreach and turn the example into this:

```
$serial = $_POST['item_code'];

foreach ($serial as $sn => $id)
{
    $finalsn = ($serial[$sn]);
    print_r(explode(',', $finalsn));
}
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => USE4220HP9
    [1] => USE4220HP8
    [2] => USE4220HP7
    [3] => USE4220HP6
    [4] => USE4220HP5
)
Array
(
    [0] => USE0463V8E
    [1] => USE1066KYN
    [2] => USE0463V7S
    [3] => USE1066KYS
    [4] => USE1066KYK
)
```

But how can I merge these two arrays into one array?  I need this to be a single array outside of the loop so that I can pass the values into a single mysql query.  I tried with array_merge but having no luck.

Comment: and your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could merge it into a final array using [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$serial = $_POST['item_code'];
$finalArray = Array();

foreach ($serial as $sn => $id)
{
    $finalsn = ($serial[$sn]);
    print_r(explode(',', $finalsn));
    $finalArray = array_merge($finalArray, explode(',', $finalsn));
}
```

Comment: This works!  Note that the code needs to be adjusted to make the explode into a variable, but I understand it now.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here, but with this `$testArr` contains all USE numbers after the iteration.

```
    $serial = $_POST['item_code'];
    $finalArr = array();
    foreach ($serial as $sn => $id)
    {
        $tmpStr = ($serial[$sn]);
        $tmpArr= explode(',', $tmpStr);
        array_push($finalArr,$tmpArr);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$serial = $_POST['item_code'];
$final_arr=array()
foreach ($serial as $sn => $id)
{
    $finalsn = ($serial[$sn]);
    $temp_arr=(explode(',', $finalsn));

    foreach($temp_arr as $temp){
          $final_arr[]=$temp;
    }

}

print_r($final_arr;)
```